Three ways of computing the probability of getting a given sequence of colors when extracting balls from an urn
I'm teaching myself some probability theory through Hans-Otto Georgii's beautiful Stochastics, and with this question I would like to clarify myself the meaning of some probabilistic models. My notation will diverge from that of the book, and anyway this post is self contained.
Suppose we're interested to model the following random experiment. Our system consists in an urn. The urn contains $ N $ colored but otherwise indistinguishable balls. To take a measurement on the system means to draw $ n $ times a ball from the urn (with always putting the extracted ball back with the others before extracting a new one), and record the sequence of colors we get. We want to compute the probability of obtaining a given sequence of colors.
A couple of ways to answer this question are the following. In any case, let's suppose that we have tagged the balls with numbers from $ 1 $ to $ N $, put $ \Omega = \{1,\dots,N\} $ and equip it with the uniform probability measure $ \mathcal U_\Omega $, and call $ \hat\Omega $ the set of all the colors. Define also an obvious random variable $ C\colon \Omega\to \hat\Omega $ that maps a ball (or better, it's unique identifier in $ \Omega $) into its color.
The first way. We can equip $ \hat\Omega $ with the pushforward probability measure $ C_*\,\mathcal U_\Omega $ and consider the product space $ \hat\Omega^n $ equipped with the product measure $ P_1 = \bigl(C_*\,\mathcal U_\Omega\bigr)^{\otimes n} $.
The second way. On the product space $ \bigl(\Omega^n,\mathcal U_\Omega^{\otimes n}\bigr) $ we define random variables $ C_i $ with values in $ \hat\Omega $ by composing the maps $ \Omega^n\xrightarrow{\mathrm{pr}_i} \Omega\xrightarrow{C} \hat\Omega $, where $ \mathrm{pr}_i $ is the obvious projection map. Each $ C_i $ induces a probability measure on $ \hat\Omega $. So, we can multiply all of these and get another probability measure $ P_2 = \bigotimes_{i = 1}^n (C_i)_*\,\mathcal U_\Omega^{\otimes n} $ on $ \hat\Omega^n $.
The third way. Almost same as before, but this time consider the pushforward measure $ P_2 = (C_1,\dots,C_n)_*\,\mathcal U_\Omega^{\otimes n} $, where $ (C_1,\dots,C_n) $ is the combined random variable of the $ C_i $s.
I was wondering, since $ P_1 = P_2 = P_3 $ above, what's the semantic difference between $ P_1 $, $ P_2 $ and $ P_3 $? I mean, if were to build a dictionary like

tensor product of measures $ \rightarrow $ iterated experiment
pushforward measure $ \rightarrow $ ???
...

then what would the process of calculating the probability of a particular outcome $ (\hat\omega_1,\dots,\hat\omega_n) $ using the function $ P_i $ sound like in these words?
What's the difference --if there is one-- between $ P_1 $, $ P_2 $ and $ P_2 $? (For example, to me using $ P_1 $ sounds more natural, but the book employs $ P_3 $, which in turn would not be equal to $ P_2 $ if the events were not independent).

Not sure this is clear.  Are you saying that the balls have different colors?  How many different colors?   Not sure why you are talking about "measure".  That's a familiar mathematical term, but I think all you mean is observation. You just want to draw $n$ balls and record the sequence of colors, right?

I don't understand what you are asking.  Suppose there are only two colors, black and white (one ball each, so two balls in total).  Then you are just looking at binary strings of length $n$.  What is your question in that case?

I'm sorry, something got messed up when I was editing the post. I'll update it in a minute, but: 1) yes, the balls might have different colors; 2) I didn't specifies how many colors there are, but since I denoted with $ \hat\Omega $ the set of colors you can just denote with $ \lvert\hat\Omega\rvert $ this number; 3) the terminology "making a measure" comes from physics, i.e., I was just trying to explain that the set of "observations" of my system is the set of all the strings of $ n $ colors; 4) yes, but (continues below)

(continued) but keep in mind that I'm more interested in understanding how the "formal"/"modern" probability theory parlance actually encodes the heuristics of "naive" probability theory.

I mean, it's clear that the result of getting $ (\mathrm{color}1,\dots,\mathrm{color}n) $ is just $ \frac{1}{N}\prod{i = 1}^n N{\mathrm{color}_i} $, but I am more interested in how we do actually encode the random experiment of extracting balls from an urn in the lingo of probability spaces random variables and such.

But considering that many people consider probability to be a subset of measure theory, it seems unwise to insist on using the word "measure" in a non standard way.   Just guaranteed to cause confusion.

Since trials are independent, you are just talking about a product measure here (using measure in the usual sense).
